# Reading Hive table partitioned files dynamically in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a variable in `Pyspark` like below

```
range = (
        (load_date='2020-06-10' AND critical in ('2', '3', '4') OR 
        (load_date='2020-06-11' AND critical in ('1', '2', '3', '4') OR
        (load_date='2020-06-12' AND critical in ('1', '2', '3', '4') OR 
        (load_date='2020-06-13' AND critical in ('1', '2', '3') 
        )
```

Now I want to read `hive` table partitioned data files that are in format like below

```
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-10/critical=2/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-10/critical=3/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-10/critical=4/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-11/critical=1/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-11/critical=2/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-11/critical=3/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-11/critical=4/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-12/critical=1/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-12/critical=2/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-12/critical=3/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-12/critical=4/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-13/critical=1/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-13/critical=2/some_files
/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-13/critical=3/some_files
```

As I have access only to `hdfs` path of the hive tables but not the actual table I cannot create a data frame directly from the `hive` tables

Now using these files I want to create a data frame like below.

```
df = spark.read
        .option("basePath", "/user/$USER")
        .parquet("/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-10/critical=2/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-10/critical=3/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-10/critical=4/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-11/critical=1/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-11/critical=2/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-11/critical=3/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-11/critical=4/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-12/critical=1/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-12/critical=2/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-12/critical=3/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-12/critical=4/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-13/critical=1/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-13/critical=2/some_files", 
                "/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-13/critical=3/some_files")
```

I am able to create the data frame but passing all the file paths in this way is a tedious and not an optimal way right. I want to do this in a simpler dynamic way

I have tried like below

```
df = spark.read
        .option("basePath", "/user/$USER")
        .parquet("/user/$USER/load_date=*/critical=*")
```

The above also works and creates the data frame.

But the problem for me is that If I use the above then I may have more data which I don't require.

For example If I have a file path

```
"/user/$USER/load_date=2020-06-13/critical=4/some_files"
```

I don't want to read that files present in the above path for now.

`requirement`

using the `range` variable extract the `load_date` and `critical` values and read only those file paths

How can I achieve that?

Comment: you can generate a `list` of all the required paths and pass it to the `read` method.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala   Can you please let me know how I can generate a list from the variable. I am a newbie to python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the root directory using `spark.read.parquet(<root-dir>)` and then apply `where` clause. This will push the predicate in the wehreclause to source path.

Let's understand this with an example-
Try this-

### 1. create the files partitioned by `batch_id`

> This is how it looks in my case `/Users/sokale/models/run_1/batch_id=73/part-00001-5fa5aebb-a836-43d2-97d2-7cf9bb722c26.c000.snappy.parquet`

```scala
  val df = spark.range(1,5)
      .withColumn("batch_id", lit(70) + col("id"))

    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+--------+
      * |id |batch_id|
      * +---+--------+
      * |1  |71      |
      * |2  |72      |
      * |3  |73      |
      * |4  |74      |
      * +---+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: long (nullable = false)
      * |-- batch_id: long (nullable = false)
      */

    df.write.partitionBy("batch_id")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .parquet("/Users/sokale/models/run_1")
    /**
      * $ cd run_1/
      * $ ls -l
      * total 0
      * ............ _SUCCESS
      * ............ batch_id=71
      * ............ batch_id=72
      * ............ batch_id=73
      * ............ batch_id=74
      */
```

### 2. Read the parquet file for partition `barch_id=73`

From the [spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/sql-programming-guide.html#configuration)-

```
spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown    default-true    Enables Parquet filter push-down optimization when set to true.
```

that means `df.read.parquet(dir).where(partitionCOndition)` only read the the specified partitioned directory using filter push down

```scala
 // read only file with batch_id=73
    spark.read.parquet("/Users/sokale/models/run_1").where(col("batch_id").equalTo(73))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+--------+
      * |id |batch_id|
      * +---+--------+
      * |3  |73      |
      * +---+--------+
      */
    // read all partitions
    val readDF = spark.read.parquet("/Users/sokale/models/run_1")
    readDF.show(false)
    readDF.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+--------+
      * |id |batch_id|
      * +---+--------+
      * |3  |73      |
      * |2  |72      |
      * |1  |71      |
      * |4  |74      |
      * +---+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: long (nullable = true)
      * |-- batch_id: integer (nullable = true)
      */
```

Comment: Actually the files I am trying to read are Hive partitioned table files. These files are not created by `spark`. and most of the time I will read only the data for which I receive the filters

Comment: I am able to read one directory but when I am trying to read multiple directories then I am facing the issues.

Comment: Can you try reading the root directory `/user/$USER` and then apply filter for `load_date` and `critical`. Also please check physical plan to check whether the predicate is getting pushed down or not?